# Add padding to the contents of a textfield

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I have a textinput component on my stage with an instance name of "myTxt"

I would like to add some left padding to the contents of this textfield. I've tried:

```
myTxt.setStyle("textPadding", 5);
```

But it adds top (and I assume bottom and right) padding in addition to the left padding. What is the best way to simply add left padding to the textfield's contents?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Updated my answer for you. Should work fine now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You use a TextFormat object for this.

```
var tf:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
tf.leftMargin = 5;
// if you have a bunch of special formatting for your TextField (fonts/sizes/etc ) 
// you will need to set it up here. 
// If you just using the default text etc you don't need to do anything else.


// you can use defaultTextFormat so you don't ever have to worry about it. 
// Just set it up once and it will keep the same formatting.
myTxt.defaultTextFormat = tf;
```

Edit: Added links to TextField and TextFormat

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/text/TextField.html

http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/text/TextFormat.html

Update: For a TextInput

```
import flash.text.TextFormat;
var tf:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
tf.leftMargin = 5;
myTxt.setStyle("textFormat", tf);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just move the TextField instance inside the component.

```
componentName.textField.x += 5;
```

Comment: I like the idea, but that code doesn't seem to work. (Using myTxt.textField.x += 5;) Any thoughts?

Comment: What type of component is myTxt? Or is it a TextField instance?

Comment: I apologize, i was wrong in the OP. It is a TextInput component. (sorry, i'm new to as3)

Comment: Ok make sure you add the component to the stage before changing the position of the TextField.

Answer (score 1):

I've been troubled with this issue.

When you apply text to the field, it resets the vertical position. To apply vertical positioning do it AFTER you put content into the field